# Django - Q.add() weird behavior when using operator OR

Tags: django, django-queryset

So, I'm trying to join a bunch of Q() queries, and in particular I want the operator to be user-defined.

In order to do that nicely I'm trying to use the Q.add(Q, operator) function, with operator received as input.

But I have ran into a weird behaviour when trying to set the operator as OR, as described below:

```
q_1 = Q(field_one__id=5)
q_2 = Q(field_two__name='foo')
print q_1
> (AND: ('field_one__id', 5))
print q_2
> (AND: ('field_two__name','foo'))
q_1_and_q_2 = Q()
q_1_or_q_2 = Q()

q_1_and_q_2.connector = q_1_and_q_2.AND # This is the default operator but just in case.
q_1_or_q_2.connector = q_1_or_q_2.OR

# joining both versions using q.add() with the pre-set operator. clone() is used to avoid overriding q_1.
q_1_and_q_2 = q_1.clone().add(q_2, q_1_and_q_2.connector)  

q_1_or_q_2 = q_1.clone().add(q_2, q_1_or_q_2.connector)

#printing q_1_and_q_2 works as expected:
print q_1_and_q_2
> (AND: ('field_one__id', 5), ('field_two__name','foo'))

#But printing q_1_or_q_2 shows that q_1 was overridden by q_2
print q_1_or_q_2 
> (AND: ('field_two__name','foo'))
```

Does anybody know why this might happen so?

I think a decent bypass would look like this:

```
from operator import or_, and_
if user_says_op == 'OR':
    op = or_
else:
    op = and_
q_1_with_q_2_operator_as_input = op(q_1,q_2)
```

But it feels wrong to do that and I'd rather use `Q.add()` if possible.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? I can't find documentation of the `clone()` method anywhere.

Comment: @Banana - clone() is indeed undocumented, but this is what it appears to be doing, you can check it with or without the q_1.clone() before you add(), and then see what happens to q_1.


Django==1.6.1

Comment: Thanks, I was using 1.5.4, where it wasn't available yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange behaviour happens because the connector of the `q_1` isn't the same as the one specified in in the `add()` method. When they aren't the same, the object inputted is returned instead of the new concatenated `Q` object.

Example:

```
>>> q_1 = Q(field_one__id=5)
>>> q_2 = Q(field_two__name='foo')
>>> q_1.connector = Q.AND
>>> print q_1.clone().add(q_2, Q.AND)
(AND: ('field_one__id', 5), ('field_two__name', 'foo')) # concatenated object
>>> q_1.connector = Q.OR
>>> print q_1.clone().add(q_2, Q.AND) 
(AND: ('field_two__name', 'foo')) # inputted data
```

**Solution**

Simply define the connector of `q_1` properly before using `add()`:

```
q_1 = Q(field_one__id=5)
q_2 = Q(field_two__name='foo')

q_1.connector = Q.AND
q_1_and_q_2 = q_1.clone().add(q_2, q_1.connector)  

q_1.connector = Q.OR
q_1_or_q_2 = q_1.clone().add(q_2, q_1.connector)

print q_1_and_q_2
print q_1_or_q_2
```

Output:

```
(AND: ('field_one__id', 5), ('field_two__name', 'foo'))
(OR: ('field_one__id', 5), ('field_two__name', 'foo'))
```

Comment: Cool, works for me too, obviously.

But why is it implemented that way?
What's the idea behind using q_1.connector as the second parameter, while it only works if the parameter is identical to the connector defined?

Comment: I'm not sure. In 1.5.4 the `add()` function didn't return anything at all, but just added the object in question. Because of that, I assume that it isn't meant to be used in this way, and therefore has other features included even though I don't fully understand them.

Comment: Gotcha.

Also, just saw that if q_2 = Q(), as in empty query, it behaves differently (variation depends on q_2.connector value).